# Pass by reference(pointer) conflict with iOS object?

Tags: ios

I've a view with few UITableView/s and UILabel/s. I'm creating them programmatically (i.e not using NIB).

I've consolidated tableView and label creation in a method with signature:

```
- (void) CreateTableView:(UITableView*) outTableView andLabel:(UILabel*)OutLabel AtFrame:(CGRect) frame{
CGRect labelFrame = frame;
labelFrame.origin.x = LABEL_LEFT_ALIGNMENT;
labelFrame.origin.y -= LABEL_TOP_ALIGNMENT;
labelFrame.size.height = LABEL_HEIGHT;
outLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];
[[self view] addSubview:outLabel];

outTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:frame style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
[outTableView setDataSource:self];
[outTableView setDelegate:self];
[[self view] addSubview:outTableView];
}
```

Here, outTableView and outLabel are output parameters. That is, after completion of method , caller will be using outTableView and outLabel.

My app has 3 tableview instance variables -- tableView1, tableView2, tableView3. And three label instance variables. View controller (caller) calls like:

```
   [self CreateTableView:tableView1 andLabel:label1 AtFrame:frame1];
   [self CreateTableView:tableView2 andLabel:label2 AtFrame:frame2];
   [self CreateTableView:tableView3 andLabel:label3 AtFrame:frame3];
```

After completion of this method, UILabel* are rendered on screen, caller able to use UILabel* object. Strangely, that is not the case with UITableView* object.

Any idea, why there is different behaviour?

Note: My application is ARC enabled.

Answer (score 2):

Wrong. The parameters won't actually contain the allocated/initialized instances, as you're passing them by value, not by reference. Consider passing a pointer to the objects then dereferencing it when allocating a new instance:

```
- (void)createTableView:(UITableView **)tvPtr
{
    *tvPtr = [[UITableView alloc] init...];
    // etc.
}
```

call like this:

```
UITableView *tv;
[self createTableView:&tv];
```

Comment: Thanks for response, H2CO3. Actually, I tried passing address of pointer. I see compilation error that is "passing address of non-local object to __autoreleasing parameter for write-back"

Comment: More over, it shall be similar as returning pointer. As we do with let say, (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *) aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath. Here, UITableViewCell* object created and returned back to framework. It is same concept. No need of Pointer to pointer.

Comment: To keep method(API) name easy to read & understand. However, I've changed it to return pointer. Actually, I wanted to get to bottom of issue where UILabel* is valid after return. Not the UITableview*. Thanks for your response, indeed.